# How to create an object of type rest_framework.request.Request to perform a get request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `get` method that is supposed to perform a GET request. I also have a `put` method that is supposed to perform a PUT request. For what I need to do I'm trying to call the `get` method inside the `put` method before any logic happens. Parts of the code is shown below:

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
  ...
  ...
  return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
  print(type(request))
  self.get(request, pk) # This is the line that I'm having trouble with.
  ...
  ...
  return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The problem I'm facing is I'm not sure how to construct the data for the `request` parameter. Using postman to send a request, when I print the type of `request` I get `<class 'rest_framework.request.Request'>`. And when I print `request` itself I get `<rest_framework.request.Request: PUT '/core/test/34500994/'>`.

I can't seem to find docs on `rest_framework.request.Request`. How do I create a `rest_framework.request.Request` object that is for a GET request that I can use as an arguement for the `put` method?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I can do the following,

```
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

factory = APIRequestFactory()
temp_get_request = factory.get('/',content_type='application/json')
converted_request = Request(temp_get_request, parsers=[JSONParser()]
```

Printing the type of `converted_request` results in `<class 'rest_framework.request.Request'>`

Comment: Okay, so you should not use a test factory for creating production code object.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me as I needed to create a request for testing purposes in django. Hope it helps somebody else.

```
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from rest_framework.request import Request

request = Request(RequestFactory().post('/irrelevant', content_type='application/json', data=data, **{
    'HTTP_X-Header-1': 'foo',
    'HTTP_X-Header-2': 'bar',
}), parsers=[JSONParser()])
request.user = xxxxxxxx
```

Basically we use the django.test.client RequestFactory to create a request, which then needs to wrapped.

Notice headers are prefixed with 'HTTP_'

Comment: Same thing. This may work but it is clearly not a good practice to use a test factory in production. Whether production code needs to initialize requests objects manually, that is another question.